# Doubt on the construction of a sentence

Tags: verbs, mathematics

I am writing a document with some mathematics and I need help with the construction of a sentence.

Is it correct to write "the function f measures the failure of the space M to be smooth"? I am not sure if there is a mistake concerning the verb "to be", it does not sound natural to me.

Comment: *Function f measures the **extent to which** the space M **is not** smooth* would be more natural so far as actual *English* is concerned. I don't know exactly what your utterance is supposed to mean, but I wonder if it might be effectively equivalent to *Function f measures the **granularity** of space M*.

Comment: Your alternative form looks good to me, I thought I may write it. However I was thinking more to how I can make my sentence correct, assuming it is not. My problem is the verb "to be", which does not sound natural to me. Granularity is not at all what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**... failure of the space *M* to be smooth** is indeed grammatical English, but I'm whether it's the usual way to express what you want is a question for Mathematics SE.

Usually you see an abstract quality being measured, such as "smoothness" or "roughness":

- The function *f* measures the **lack of smoothness** of the space *M*

Here are a couple of examples from published papers:

Smoothness:

> ... certain geometric measures of smoothness ... (https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212668)

Roughness::

> It is well-known that random functions are typically “rough” (non-differentiable), which raise the question of determining and measuring roughness. Probably, the most studied roughness measures are the Hausdorff dimension and the *p*−variation index. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0489.pdf)

Lack-of-smoothness:

> Multidimensional Whittaker graduations are obtained by minimizing a linear combination of a measure of lack-of-fit between the graduated and ungraduated values, and measures of lack-of-smoothness of the graduated values across each dimension. (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167668795000216)

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but I think saying "the function f measures the lack of smoothness of M" does not really address my point. I used the expression "measures the failure of" because I saw this expression on a book written by an English author. I was just wondering whether the verb "to be" after it is correct in this form.

Comment: I updated the answer to directly address this, hope that's better.

Comment: I just found an example on a published paper: "the tensor f measures the failure of a manifold to be (...)", so I am more positive my construction was correct.